# GLSL ES 2: Is it safe to use uniforms as colors/vectors' array subscripts?

Tags: opengl-es

The intention is:

- Sample a texture and get the color.
- Instead of getting color components via .x/y/z/r/g/b, it would be convenient to use this form: **theColor[theIntUniform]**, which is called array subscripting notation.

In OpengGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide:

1. "One thing you need to be
   careful of, though, is that if you access a vector with a **non-constant integral
   expression (e.g., using an integer variable index), then this might not be
   supported in OpenGL ES 2**.0."
2. "OpenGL ES 2.0 spec does not mandate support for this behavior **except for
   on a specific variable type (namely, uniform** variables)."

Does the 2nd sentence say "uniforms can be used as array subscripts" or "can indexing uniform vectors with non-consts"?
(https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf
P110, see the table in Summary, it really means the later.)

Based on my understanding, uniforms are actually constant for shaders, so **is it safe to use it like: theColor[theIntUniform]?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> is it safe to use it like: theColor[theIntUniform]?

It isn't guaranteed to work. Section 5.5 OpenGL ES Shading Language v1.0 spec states that:

> any integer expression can be used as the subscript

... which sounds like it should work, but then section 10.25 states:

> Dynamic indexing of arrays, vectors and matrices is not directly supported by some implementations. ... Should dynamic indexing of vectors and matrices be removed from the specification?
>   RESOLUTION: Keep in main specification. Support is not mandated.

However, even if supported it is not really a good idea to do it this way. On most mobile architectures in my experience dynamic or uniform-based indexing is likely to be slower than using constant indexing or the swizzle syntax (which is known as compile time, and therefore can be "inlined" by the compiler and directly encoded in the instructions).

Comment: Thank you! A little bit slower is acceptable, after all, using another dynamic approach (dot a uniform vector to select a component) could be even more slower. I just want to make sure if this works.

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed to work, as described by the Programming Guide, it does not work for variables.

Comment: @macrod Any idea which bit of the OpenGL ES Shading Language v1.0 specification document prohibits it? The section I referenced seems to explicitly allow variable indexing, it specifically states "any" integer expression can be an array subscript for vector indexing. There is no mention of a need for this to be either a compile time constant expression or a uniform expression.

Comment: Found it lurking as a footnote in Section 10.25 - quite right, it's not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Well, by saying "any integer", the spec could mean (which is not really clear), any integer as index to uniform vectors, there are 2 occurrences of "any integer" in https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf.